# Why does my unity buttons stopped working?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm following an online course and then I noticed that the buttons just stopped working.

Here are some images [The Scene View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sW2rX.jpg), [Game Over Canvas Components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKH9w.jpg), [Game Over Text Components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afZZE.jpg), [Restart Button Components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqShO.jpg)(The Broken Button), [Leave Text Components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWKLt.jpg)(The Other Broken Button), [The Script That Have Something to do with the canvas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZuG6.jpg).

I've tried multiple solutions on the internet and nothing works and I think I didn't mess with anything else but the colors and the text in the button. I just want the buttons to work like it's a button.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `EventSystem` Object maybe deleted or disabled, try to recreate it:

[image: Component structure]

It will created automatically when you create UI/Canvas:

[image: Event system under Canvas]